# assembly - x86_64 - predicates

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86-64, predicate

I am coding some assembly for x86_64 and arm.

I would like to know whether x86_64 has some ways to define branch predicates.

I searched in Intel documentation but failed to find relevant info.

We have `cmov` but it is rather slow and a `cmp jmp` combo **tends** to be faster.

Comment: Showing some code will most likely help people answer your question faster.

Comment: Alas, x86_64 does not have predicates in the sense that ARM does.

Comment: What a shame! Thanks!

Comment: Modern-day ARM (Thumb-2, AArch64) doesn't have them, either. Not to the extent of the legacy instruction set.

Comment: With recent microarchitectures, CMOV is not slow. In the past it was slow-ish but according to the Intel Optimization manual and Agner Fog instruction timing tables, CMOV is single cycle on Broadwell (2014) and newer microarchitectures. On P4 F4 it was 10 cycles. That's slow. On Core 2 through Haswell, it was two cycles. (https://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf) There's an old Linus rant about CMOV but that was from 2007 and Intel has improved their implementations since. Moreover, they recommend CMOV for a variety of reasons. So if CMOV fits, you should use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM predicates are an *alternative* to branches.  IDK what you mean by "branch predicates".  Maybe you mean "predicate conditions"?

`cmov` is often worth it compared to a branch that only skips over one or two instructions, if it's at all unpredictable.  Broadwell and Skylake run cmov as a single uop, but previous microarchitectures need 2 uops since it has 3 input dependencies.  It also creates a data dependency instead of a control dependency.  Branch prediction, when it works, can be better.  Also, `cmov` can't take an immediate operand, which is frustrating in many cases.

Another instruction that can use a condition as an input is `setcc`.  Use `xor reg,reg` / set flags / `setcc low-byte-of-reg`, to avoid partial-reg stalls when reading the full register.

For the carry condition, `sbb same,same` will produce 0 or -1 (useful as an AND mask), or `adc reg, 0` will do `reg += CF`.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Will give it a shot